# In the 2015 Supergirl pilot, why do they avoid saying "Superman"?

Tags: dc, superman, arrowverse, supergirl, supergirl-2015

They call him "the other guy", "the guy in blue", "my cousin", "him", "the male", etc.  but they are clearly avoiding referring to him as "Superman".  Is it a production choice to keep focus on this show?  Is it a legal issue?  (The answer must be out of universe because it's clear from the show he is known by that name,  it's just not said.)

Comment: Having only seen the `(extended) trailer, I would go with your "keeping focus on the show" idea - since that **is** kinda the point of a trailer after all and would assume they will namedrop Superman in the actual pilot, which I assumed wasn't out yet, or is it?

Comment: **SPOILER WARNING** - http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=297&t=18484 - **SPOILER WARNING**

Comment: @bmwurm - The pilot has (/ahem) leaked onto social media. If you can call '*intentionally released* **by the studio** *to create hype*' a leak, that is.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/05/supergirl-leaked-pilot-an-almost-completely-spoiler-free-review/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Out-of-universe, it's likely just a technique used to prevent viewers from dwelling on the humongous 'elephant in the room' (e.g. where's Superman and **why aren't we watching him instead?**).

They do actually [reference him](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=297&t=18484) by *all* of his comic-book names; Superman, The Man of Steel and Kal-el so it's not like he was *totally* excluded, just not name-dropped eight times.

> *When I arrived, I was still a 13-year-old girl. But in that same time
>   **my cousin Kal-El** had grown up and revealed himself to your world... **as
>   Superman. The most powerful man in the universe.***

and

> *The big question: is there a connection between this mysterious flying
>   woman and **the Man of Steel?***

The show's Executive Producer addressed the lack of Superman in an [interview with CinemaBlend](http://www.cinemablend.com/television/Blunt-Reason-Superman-Supergirl-92647.html):

> I think the reason why Superman’s not in the show is because it’s not
>   about him. And it’s her show and it’s about her and he is just sort of
>   a shadow in the back of her psyche, and I think that’s the right way
>   to portray him because that’s how she experiences it.

---

In-Universe, I suspect that people avoid saying his name for a *variety* of reasons. Jimmy, Kara and her sister Alex have all trained themselves to be discreet (since you never know who's listening) and her boss; Cat Grant seems to be somewhat more scathing and ironic about him, basically refusing to call him by his given name.

Comment: Given how much flak *Agents of SHIELD* took for constantly reminding us of Coulson's role in *The Avengers*, it's probably a smart decision.

Comment: 1)   This didn't say "Superman".   And reference here http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/05/supergirl-leaked-pilot-an-almost-completely-spoiler-free-review/ and the second comment thereon (AndyF), and you will see other people noticed this too.

Comment: @Thepopmachine - I've checked the transcript and they did indeed say Superman as well as "the Man of Steel" and Kal-el.

Comment: Link?   Need to check the video.


 But suffice it to say, they hardly say it.

Comment: @Thepopmachine - Link is in the comments on the question. I agree that they tried to avoid saying it.

Comment: While this is obviously the right answer, it would have even better had they stopped referring to him *at all* every 5 minutes :\

Answer (score 1):

Around the 2:20 minute mark:

"When I arrived I was still a 13 year old girl. But in that same time my cousin, Kal-El, had grown up and revealed himself to your world... as Superman. The most powerful man in the Universe."

That's the first of at least three mentions of "Superman" (and Kal-El is said even from the first few seconds of the episode).

Comment: Are you sure it was said three times? I can only recall it being said once and the [transcripts](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=supergirl-2015&episode=s01e00) seem to [agree](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=297&t=18484) with that

Comment: Downvoted. I'm afraid this answer is simply wrong.