# Are there conditions to Superman's appearances in Supergirl?

Tags: dc, superman, arrowverse, supergirl, supergirl-2015

Related: [In the 2015 Supergirl pilot, why do they avoid saying "Superman"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90690/in-the-2015-supergirl-pilot-why-do-they-avoid-saying-superman)

Superman's appearances in *Supergirl* so far have been fleeting. As far as I can tell, his face hasn't been shown. The sun's behind him in the scene where he finds Supergirl the first time, and in episode 3 he's shown from Supergirl's (prone) view from behind.

### Is it just to decrease his prominence? Or, are there (possibly contractual or licensing) conditions to his appearance in the show?

<sub><sup>IMHO trying to not show his face seems rather clumsy - it heightens curiosity as to what he looks like, and thereby increases attention to Superman.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to executive producer Sarah Shechter, quoted [here](http://www.cinemablend.com/television/Blunt-Reason-Superman-Supergirl-92647.html):

> I think the reason why Superman’s not in the show is because it’s not about him. And it’s her show and it’s about her and he is just sort of a shadow in the back of her psyche, and I think that’s the right way to portray him because that’s how she experiences it.

See also the article [Superman's Not in the Show Because It's Not About Him](http://www.hitfix.com/whats-alan-watching/supergirl-producers-supermans-not-in-the-show-is-because-its-not-about-him).

Comment: That's ... disappointing. Either I lack an appreciation for finer subtleties, or they lack in execution of subtlety. Either way, this is not the place for rants.

Comment: Now we know the condition: they just had to change production houses (if that's the term)